# Find maximum of $|\sqrt{x^4-7x^2-4x+20}-\sqrt{x^4+9x^2+16}|$ without using calculus

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, maxima-minima

> Find maximum of $|\sqrt{x^4-7x^2-4x+20}-\sqrt{x^4+9x^2+16}|$ without using any calculus

I believe I have made most of the progress but am stuck on the last step

I rewrote the expression as- $$\left|\sqrt{(x^2-4)^2+(x-2)^2}-\sqrt{(x^2+4)^2+(x-0)^2}\right|$$

We notice that this is written in the format of the distance formula. In particular, this is the expression for the difference of distances from an arbitrary point $(x^2,x)$ and $(4,2)$,$(-4,0)$ respectively.

[image]

In this figure we have to find maximum of $|PA-PB|$

I could not think of how this could be maximised. Usually in questions like these $P$ somehow is collinear or lies on the reflection of some given point but nothing of that sort can happen here. I tried a few special points as well like $(4,-2),(0,0)$ etc.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: @TonyK yes, thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between the distances to each of those two points is maximised over the whole plane by any point on the straight line $AB$ that does not lie strictly between $A$ and $B$; and this maximum value is simply $|AB|=2\sqrt{17}$.

And your curve touches this line at $A$ when $x=2$; so the maximum value of the expression is $2\sqrt{17}$, achieved when $x=2$.

Comment: I made a mistake while looking at the distance, I thought it was $7.2…$ instead of $8.2…>8$ I've edited my question so that someone in the future looking at this does not get confused; Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4):

By the triangle inequality, for every point $P$,
$$||PA|-|PB||\leq |AB|$$
so the maximum is attained when $P=A$.